# Scipy questions/support?

Tags: discussion

I assume that some or even many here use SciPy for DSP.

What do you use for support? I've found [SciPy-user mailing list](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/mailing-lists.html), but it doesn't seem that active.

Is [dsp.stackexchange.com](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) useful/suitable for SciPy questions?

Answer (score 4):

Generally, programming questions are considered as being off-topic. We are trying to be language-agnostic in here. Strict programming questions belong to Stack Overflow.

Obviously there are some exceptions, when source code is a nice thing to have. Then one might consider writing a working example in language of their choice (MATLAB/Python/R).

My other [answer](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1365/8202) should shed some light on it.

Answer (score 4):

As @Bookend says, there is an active [Stackoverflow tag of `scipy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scipy) that you should use for debugging questions on that site.

If there are lists of resources that we should compile here, then it looks like Stackoverflow itself allows some of them. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for example. However, I don't think `scipy` quite falls into the category of C and C++.